# Edit response logo in web2py

Tags: python, frameworks, response, web2py

I am trying to edit the default logo to my own in my MODEL(menu.py).
The default code for the logo is:

```
response.logo = A(B('web',SPAN(2),'py'),XML('&trade;&nbsp;'), _class="brand", _href="http://www.web2py.com/")
```

How would I change this line to display my own logo? For instance, the url for the logo might be something like "http://www.web2py.com/init/static/images/logo_lb.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the content of the anchor tag to include the image:

```
response.logo = A(IMG(_src=URL('static', 'images/logo_lb.png'),
                  _href=URL('default', 'index'))
```

Note, you don't really need to use `response.logo` at all. You can instead just put the relevant HTML directly in the layout.html view.